# Xcode build fails if build directory involves a symbolic link

Tags: xcode, cmake, symlink

I have a cmake project from which I create an `Xcode` project:

```
cd mybuilddir
cmake /path/to/project -G Xcode
cmake --build .
```

This gives me a linking error. Creating a `makefile` project using:

```
cd mybuilddir
cmake /path/to/project
cmake --build .
```

works fine.

After several hours I figured out that `mybuilddir` 
is actually a symbolic link. Removing the symbolic link or entering the directory not via the symbolic link solves the problem. 
The problem never occured to me before but `make` and `Xcode` should definitely give the same results.

I merely post this here to save some other peoples time.

I'm using `cmake 3.14` and `Xcode 10.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases a `Xcode` project created via `cmake` does not compile properly if the build directory involves a symbolic link.